# What does it mean by android support status "Discontinued"

Tags: android, security

From wiki page of [Android version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) I found that Android 4.4 version support status was discontinued. If I want to develop one app with minimum support version as Android 4.4, how will it impact?

And where I can find the official statement by Google about this.

Comment: "From wiki page of Android version history I found that Android 4.4 version support status was discontinued" -- possibly, that refers to whether Google backports security patches, though that is just a guess. "If I want to develop one app with minimum support version as Android 4.4, how will it impact?" -- if that refers to Google's security patches, your app is not directly affected. "And where I can find the official statement by Google about this" -- ask whoever wrote that Wikipedia page what they meant.

Comment: @CommonsWare If my issue is about security patches, and as Google discontinued for 4.4, hackers can exploit my app. I think this will impact my decision to support 4.4 or not. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: "If my issue is about security patches, and as Google discontinued for 4.4, hackers can exploit my app" -- they can "exploit" your app on supported versions too, then. Just because *Google* makes security fixes available does not mean that *users* get those fixes, due to decisions of device manufacturers and, to a lesser extent, mobile carriers.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, that's what my question Security patches depends on OEMs mainly so what should I understand from this 'Discontinued' statement?

Comment: As a developer, you should ignore it. Occasionally, there is a security issue that represents something that developers can actually work around, such as [2016's `ExifInterface` bug](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/08/dealing-exifinterface-security-flaw.html), which eventually led to [a new support library](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/12/15/about-support-exifinterface.html). I and others will try to point those out. Otherwise, whether a given version of Android is or is not getting security fixes is not particularly relevant to you as a developer.

Comment: As a *user*, buy official Google hardware or from a manufacturer with a good track record of shipping security updates. Then, when you see that there will be no more security updates (or you just stop getting them), consider moving to a newer device.